# Table not updating with wordpress dbdelta

Tags: wordpress

I have following code for creating table:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . "("
         . "id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "
         . "product_id mediumint(9) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,"
         . "name_type mediumint(9) NOT NULL, "
         . "name_key varchar(48) NOT NULL, "
         . "valid_until datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL, "
         . "created_at datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL, "
         . "updated_at datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL, "
         . "UNIQUE KEY id (id)"
         . ")" . $charset_collate. ";";
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
```

It is working and table created.

Now I need update table and add new column (sites_list):

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . "("
         . "id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "
         . "product_id mediumint(9) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,"
         . "name_type mediumint(9) NOT NULL, "
         . "name_key varchar(48) NOT NULL, "
         . "sites_list longtext, "
         . "valid_until datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL, "
         . "created_at datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL, "
         . "updated_at datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL, "
         . "UNIQUE KEY id (id)"
         . ")" . $charset_collate. ";";
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
```

But  this not work.

And I has a error:

```
WordPress database error: [Table 'table_name' already exists]
```

What is incorrect?

Thanks.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You can't create the table because it already exists. You probably want `ALTER TABLE` or `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`

Comment: Yes, this will be great, but from codex: _The dbDelta function examines the current table structure, compares it to the desired table structure, and either adds or modifies the table as necessary, so it can be very handy for updates_. [link]http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table 
I think the using **dbdelta** more correctly to update the plugin

Comment: This issue is probably that your fields are not actually on separate lines (this is one of the "conditions" set out by the function. The reason for this is you're concatenating the string and this will actually result in a single line. I'll add an answer and try and explain this a little better.

Comment: I'm trying removing concatenation, but nothing changed. Error is same.

Answer (score 5):

You've used the dbDelta function incorrectly.

- You have to put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.
- You have to have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the definition of your primary key.
- You must use the keyword KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you must include at least one KEY.

http://hungred.com/how-to/wordpress-dbdelta-function/

Answer (score 1):

The code itself of the dbDelta function is very complex. But with trial-and-error, I've noticed some behaviors of the dbDelta function **update** behavior:

- It doesn't rename the Primary Key column
- It doesn't remove a column
- If you try to rename an old column, it will just create a new column and keep the old one.

#### Long explanation

dbDelta is a function that people usually tell to hook at `register_activation_hook`, but this doesn't fire on plugin updates, so it wouldn't create the tables for your users that are upgrading an existing install. So the first thing to get dbDelta updates to work, is to hook it on `admin_init`.

However, this is a pretty heavy function, so it must only run when needed. For this, you can keep a `my_plugin_db_version` option in the database, and use it to check if you should run the dbDelta or not.

If you already have an autoloaded option being loaded, it's even better to use that, as the check will have zero performance impact, as autoloaded options are loaded in-memory at the beginning of WordPress life-cycle.

This, in code, can be expressed as:

```php
add_action('admin_init', 'my_plugin_maybe_run_delta');

function my_plugin_maybe_run_delta() {
  // Here we are not using an existing autoloaded option to keep the example short
  $dbVersion = get_option('my_plugin_db_version');

  // Early bail: No need to run dbDelta
  if ($dbVersion === '1.0.0') {
    return;
  }

  // dbDelta here...

  // Now set the db version so it can early bail next time...
  update_option('my_plugin_db_version', '1.0.0', false);
}
```

Now let's suppose that I have this dbDelta on version 1.0 of my plugin:

```php
global $wpdb;
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

$tableName = $wpdb->prefix . 'foo';
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tableName (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  event longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) $charset_collate;";

dbDelta($sql);

// Some error happened during dbDelta.
if (!empty($lastErrorBefore) && $lastErrorBefore !== $wpdb->last_error) {
    // handle error
}
```

This produces the following DDL in the database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `wp_foo` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Now I decide to rename `id` to `event_id`, so I change the dbDelta and release the version 1.1 of the plugin:

```php
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tableName (
  event_id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  event longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (event_id)
) $charset_collate;";
```

This delta won't change the db structure for users that are upgrading the plugin, they will have the primary key as `id`, while new installs will have the primary key as `event_id`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `wp_foo` (
  `event_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

So rule #1 of dbDelta: It doesn't renames the Primary Key column.

Now, on version 1.2, I want to rename `event` to `events`, so I modify the dbDelta like this:

```php
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $tableName (
  event_id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  events longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (event_id)
) $charset_collate;";
```

This will produce the following result for users that upgrade from 1.1 to 1.2:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `wp_foo` (
  `event_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `events` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

While producing the following result for fresh installs:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `wp_wpstg_analytics` (
  `event_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `events` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

While producing the following result for users that use the plugin since 1.0:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `wp_wpstg_analytics` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `events` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Which is a pretty reasonable behavior when you come to think about it. If you rename the column `event` to `events`, you can still migrate the data from the old column to the new for previous installs. Just remember to never rename the column that is assigned as Primary Key.